# System.Quiddity Enum sync vs async

Tags: apex, executioncontext

With the new [Winter '21](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter21/release-notes/rn_apex_Runtime_Detection.htm) release, salesforce makes it much easier to detect what is a current running context by means of [Request.getCurrent().getQuiddity()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Request.htm) method. This is great,  thank you, salesforce.

```
//Get info about the current request
Request reqInfo = Request.getCurrent();

//Universally unique identifier for this request
//Same as requestId in splunk or REQUEST_ID in event monitoring
String currentRequestId = reqInfo.getRequestId();


//enum representing how Apex is running. e.g. BULK_API vs LIGHTNING
//Use this with a switch statement,
//instead of checking System.isFuture() || System.isQueueable() || ...
Quiddity currentType = reqInfo.getQuiddity();
```

There is a list of [System.Quiddity](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_enum_System_Quiddity.htm#topic-title) enumeration, for example, ANONYMOUS, AURA, etc.

[Apex Per-Transaction Governor Limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_apexgov.htm) are divided into two parts: synchronous limit and asynchronous limit. Some of them are different, for example, total number of SOQL queries issued, maximum number of Apex jobs added to the queue with `System.enqueueJob`.

Finally, question. Is there any documentation, that could point, which enumeration is **sync** execution, and which is **async**?

Comment: Wouldn't `SYNCHRONOUS`, `FUTURE`, or `QUEUEABLE` provide the information you're looking for?

Comment: @KrisGoncalves for most cases, that should be enough.   but in making a managed package I need to cover all possible values.

Comment: @OleksandrBerehovskyi given the time since you raised this question, do you have an answer you can share here?

Comment: @PhilW nope, not yet, unfortunately. For my use case I was just checking if quiddity is `BATCH_ACS, BATCH_APEX, BATCH_CHUNK_PARALLEL, BATCH_CHUNK_SERIAL, FUTURE, QUEUEABLE, SCHEDULED, TRANSACTION_FINALIZER_QUEUEABLE` and I considered that as async transaction.

Comment: @PhilW Can one of you create an idea for it or point us towards an idea if that exists? Might be worth while to get product look at it closely.

Comment: It struck me that to check sync vs async is already identifiable by checking one of the variable limits, such as CPU. To allow for platform behaviour change, simply check if the `Limits.getLimitCpuTime() < 50000` for sync, otherwise async...?

Comment: Sounds like a workaround and there might be a better performant way to do this natively.